# Recorrer un objeto de json de Firebase

Tags: json, firebase, select

estoy aprendiendo a usar firebase y pues quiero o intente recorrer un objeto json que me tira firebase para poder ponerlo en select, este es mi objeto

```
{"-MEunvhn8r7ZrznJB5a9":{"description":"Peperoni and cheese","name":"Pepe & Roni","price":"122","suggestion":"tasty with extra sauce"},"-MEzXSuGk0MyHJzOiePA":{"description":"Only Cheese","name":"Cheese Pizza","price":"112","suggestion":"tasty with extra salt"}}
```

entonces trate de pasarlo por un `foreach` pero me tira este error

> Uncaught TypeError: resp.forEach is not a function

Esto es lo que estoy haciendo.

```
function getDrinks(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/get/drinks-list/',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(resp) {
            console.log(resp);
            $('#selectDrinks').empty();   
            resp.forEach(e => {
                //ese key que tengo es _Mblabalblasoy key y quiero pasarlo a mi select
                $('#selectDrinks').append(`<option value="${e.key}">${e.name}</option>`);
            });
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            var data = jqXHR.responseJSON;
            if (jqXHR.status == 401) {
                //location.reload();
            }
            console.log(errorThrown)

        }
    });
}
```

Eventualmente querre correr esto en otro lenguaje de programacion, alguien me podria decir como puedo reccorrer estos objetos, alguien podria ayudarme por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar haciendo esto

```
function getDrinks(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/get/drinks-list/',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(resp) {
            console.log(resp);
            $('#selectDrinks').empty();   
            Object.keys(resp).forEach(key => {
              $('#selectDrinks').append(`<option value="${key}">${resp[key].name}</option>`);
            });
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            var data = jqXHR.responseJSON;
            if (jqXHR.status == 401) {
                //location.reload();
            }
            console.log(errorThrown)

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias funciono perfecto, podrias compartirme tu referencia?

Comment: Lo que devuelve realtime database de firebase es un objeto y no un array por eso no puedes iterar y cada key es el id que esta guardado en la base de datos